# EJB call a method between two beans

Tags: ejb, javabeans, stateless, stateful

I have got two Beans. One Stateful and one Stateless. Now I want to call a method, which is  in the stateless bean, from the stateful bean. How can I do this? The stateless bean has also got an interface.

Comment: Could you describe what is your problem exactly? Did you try to do this and it didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using EJB3.0. So, put in your Stateful bean:

@EJB
private YourStatelessBeanInterface statelessBean;